# How to output two different labels on two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that shows a label when clicking the button, but I need the following:

- Two buttons showing two different labels, in one of the buttons show your label below that button;
- When a label is active or shown by clicking on the other button, that label is replaced by the new one.

```js
(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $("#action").html("button was clicked");
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this button has default style -->
<button>Action</button>

<label id="action"></label>
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/fr4x32g7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function () {
  var active = "";
  $('button').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = "#" + e.target.value;
    $(active).html("");
    active = id;
    $(id).html("button was clicked");
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this button has default style -->
<button value="action">Action</button>
<label id="action"></label>
<button value="action1">Action</button>
<label id="action1"></label>
```

Comment: Yes this solution can also solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does this solve the problem ?

```js
(function() {
  $('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $("#action").html("button1 was clicked");
  });
  $('#button2').on('click', function() {
    $("#action").html("button2 was clicked");
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this button has default style -->
<button id="button1">Action1</button>
<button id="button2">Action2</button>


<label id="action"></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that both labels are to be hidden initially and to show only one of them if the user clicks on a button. Here's a solution:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this button has default style -->
<button data-label="action1">Action 1</button>
<button data-label="action2">Action 2</button>
<br>
<label class="action" id="action1" style="display:none;">button 1 was clicked</label>
<label class="action" id="action2" style="display:none;">button 2 was clicked</label>
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data('label')).show().siblings("label").hide();
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0phz62ot/

Basically we bind the button with its label via an attribute and whenever a button is clicked, the label bound to it will be shown and the sibling labels will be hidden.

Comment: Yes this solution can also solve the problem, thanks.